# Is kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1 compatible with Zookeeper 3.4.12?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Currently we are using Apache kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1 and Apache Solr 5.5 with Zookeeper 3.4.6.
But we are upgrading Apache Solr, hence need to upgrade Zookeeper to 3.4.12.
Kafka is working with this zookeeper version as per our basic testing done. But we just want to confirm whether or not Zookeeper 3.4.12 is officially supported with kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will work (just tested), but without backing up the Kafka data in Zookeeper and restoring it to the new one, then you will lose all the Kafka data, meaning your topics and committed offsets will be lost.

FWIW, it might be worth upgrading Kafka as well.

Comment: Will data be lost Even if we do a rolling restart while upgrading Zookeeper ?

Comment: Yes, but rolling upgrades generally keep the same zookeepers. Without a backup, the cluster metadata mentioned is what's being lost here, not the log data on the broker machines. I assume the same can be said about your Solr Collection names, or whatever Solr is storing in Zookeeper